# How can I extract the embedded prompt configuration from AI-generated images?

Tags: image-generation, image, prompt-configuration

Some frontend AI image generation tools embed metadata (e.g. prompt configuration) in their images. Example:

- ComfyUI & Automatic1111: PNG text chunks

While the same tools can read the configuration by opening the generated images, not everyone has access to the tools, and textual information can be shared more universally for anyone else trying to reproduce the image using their own favorite frontend tools.

How can I extract the prompt configuration from AI-generated images?

---

<sup>This question is inspired by [Can we preserve the EXIF data of AI-generated images?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/can-we-preserve-the-exif-data-of-ai-generated-images) as a possible workaround solution.</sup>

Comment: I intend to make this a canonical Q&A, though I admit I can see 2 possible issues: 1) too broad, but canonical questions tend to be broad but specific, and 2) [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for "sharing human-readable prompt configuration for AI-generated images".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several tools available that allow you to view PNG chunks, in particular the text chunks where ComfyUI and Automatic1111 store their metadata.

**Online:**

- https://www.nayuki.io/page/png-file-chunk-inspector
- https://www.dcode.fr/png-chunks

**Local:**

- https://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Automatic1111's stored metadata is relatively simple and human-readable:

[image: Automatic1111 metadata]

ComfyUI stores the prompt and a more-involved full workflow graph as JSON:

[image: ComfyUI metadata]

Note that [ComfyUI](https://github.com/comfyanonymous/ComfyUI) and [Automatic1111's web UI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) are FOSS, available for free, don't require being able to load a model on your GPU just to run the interface itself, and could even be ran on services like Google Colab. Particularly for ComfyUI, the best choice would normally be to load the image back into the interface it was created with - if you know which one.

---

Below are a couple of test images that you can download and check for metadata.

ComfyUI:

[image: Bottle with ComfyUI metadata]

Automatic1111:

[image: Tomato with Automatic1111 metadata]